# URLopen error when trying to download a file using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to use `urllib.request.retrieve` to download a csv file, but it returns the error shown below:

```
name = str(links[0])
url = 'https://betfairsp/prices/'
file = url + name
file

'https://betfairsp/prices/dwbfgreyhoundplace15042020.csv'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(file)
```

> URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Looks like the hostname `betfairsp` isn’t valid. No `.com`?

Comment: lack of attention. thanks